# keras : load_img file shows no moduled name scipy

Tags: python, scipy

I am new to keras and deep learning projects.when i import

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
```

in python shell it works  perfectly. but when i do run in the editor it throws error

> from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/preprocessing/image.py",       line 10, in 
>       from scipy import linalg
>         ImportError: No module named scipy

when i checked

> python -m pip list

scipy and and all other packages is installed ..

my pip installed packages are

```
scikit-learn (0.19.1)
scipy (1.0.0)
service-identity (16.0.0)
setuptools (20.7.0)
simplegeneric (0.8.1)
singledispatch (3.4.0.3)
six (1.11.0)
```

The same error thrown when i used

```
form sklearn.utils import shuffle
```

but all work perfectly fine when i work on python shell.

Comment: Then your editor, which actually looks more like an IDE, uses the wrong python-interpreter (paths!).

Comment: will check that...! i use sublime editor.. is it take default path as /usr/local/python2.7/dist-packages/ ?